# how to select the cell below on a different sheet to populate a cell next to one on your worksheet

Tags: excel, reference, excel-2007, drag

I am tasked with creating A map of our warehouse.

In the data I have to have model, description and location.

What I am having trouble with is, I am using data from a second sheet to populate the "map"

i.e. `='1'!F2`
when I try to drag and use it to fill an entire line it changes to `='1'!g2`.  I would like it to go to `='1'!F3`

I see the logic in what it is doing...but I dont want it to use that logic..I want it to use the next cell below it to populate that cell.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing might be to Copy and then Paste Special > Transpose the data on "1" to a new sheet.  Then you could drag formulas that refer to the new sheet and they'd behave as expected.

EDIT: Based on your original question, this will fill in the results of columns to the right as you drag it down and vice-versa.  This literally does what your original question asked:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$F$2:$Z$8000,COLUMN(),ROW())
```

Start in A1 and drag in either direction.  To add a header line or rows to left just insert rows or columns to top or left (to keep the formula sound).

EDIT:  Here's the Transpose function, per @brettdj's suggestion.  I find it difficult to work with, but it certainly makes it clearer what's going on:

In cells F2:8000 of your target sheet enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!$F2:$Z8000)
```

Then, with all those cells selected, go into edit mode in one of the cells and do `Ctrl Shft Enter` to array-enter it.  If you have to resize the source range I believe you have to repeat these steps with the correct ranges.  I'm an Index fan myself, so would stick with that.  Offset is volatile, so I'd avoid it.  If I've got any of this last edit wrong, @brettdj will help us.

Comment: Thanks for that Doug, I would do that, except for the 8000 + items I need to populate the "map"  for. I started doing this and then thought there HAS to be an easier method.  I am curently using the Indirect argument...but that causes a need to change a few values to get it right. I know there has to be an easier method and I am too fried to think of it.

Comment: I need a better description of the sheet you are copying from and the desired end result.  It sounds like on one there are 8000 rows of data that you want to read into 8000 columns.  Because you're expecting to just drag the formula, I assumed that simply transposing the data to an intermediate sheet would suffice, but it sounds like there are other issues.

Comment: +1. You cold also use the `TRANSPOSE` formula directlty (array entered), or an `OFFSET`. The `TRANSPOSE` being more transparent and auditable.

Comment: @brettdj, thanks, I added the Transpose version, but may not have got it right.  I never think of it, and using it just now, I had to figure out the order and method of entry.  Also I always try to avoid array-entered formulas (hate that message about not being able to change part of an array, I mean it's my array, I should be able to do what I want).  Plus, Index is my favorite Excel function.  Finally, just let me say a ever-so-slightly early congrats on 5000!

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is non-native behaviour, it might be worth writing a small VBA macro to do the copy, and assign it to a keyboard shortcut.

Here's a simple example to copy a formula one cell to right, updating reference one cell down (preserves Absolute/Relative settings in formula).
It assumes `A1` style address, work only if the active cell contains a formula referencing a single cell (ends silently if not).  Will silently overwrite anything in the destination cell.

```
Sub CopyToRight()
    Dim clFrom As Range
    Dim clAddr As Range
    Dim addr As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set clFrom = ActiveCell
    If clFrom.Formula Like "=*!*" Then
        Set clAddr = Range(Mid(clFrom.Formula, 2))
        If clAddr.Count = 1 Then
            If clFrom.Formula Like "=*!$*$*" Then
                addr = clAddr.Offset(1, 0).Address(True, True)
            ElseIf clFrom.Formula Like "=*!$**" Then
                addr = clAddr.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, True)
            ElseIf clFrom.Formula Like "=*!*$*" Then
                addr = clAddr.Offset(1, 0).Address(True, False)
            Else
                addr = clAddr.Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False)
            End If
            clFrom.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "='" & clAddr.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & addr 
        End If
    End If
    clFrom.Offset(0, 1).Select
EH:
End Sub
```